# unwanted "flickering" effect when using hide and show in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm getting an annoying "flickering" effect in Firefox when using jQuery "show" and "hide" on some div's.  Any idea when this could be happening?

Comment: Do the divs have background images? Transparent pngs?

Comment: @craigmoliver: Example of your code would be good.

Comment: Code examples and a description of what browsers and systems you have used would be good.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depending on what you mean by flicker (if it only flickers when the page loads), instead of doing:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("hide").hide();
});

<div id="hide">My Hidden Text</div>
```

Try adding display:none in the CSS:

```
<div id="hide" style="display:none">My Hidden Text</a>
```

CSS is applied to the DOM before even JavaScript is allowed to manipulate it, so if you do this, there should be no flicker when you load the page.

Also of note, in Firefox, there is a bug that causes the window to flicker when you change the size of the window (vertically), and the current scroll position is close or at the bottom of the window.

Answer (score 6):

The flicker comes from this line of the jQuery code, in the show() method:

```
 var elem = jQuery("<" + tagName + " />").appendTo("body");
```

It does that to detect the CSS it should use for the display attribute, since different tags get different values (div: block, span: inline, tr: table-row, etc).  Manipulating the DOM in this way causes the flicker.

Use:

```
jQuery('...').css('display','block');
```

which will generally do the same thing.

Comment: I've heard this before and remember this being the fix. I think this is the best answer as it explains why its happening and why the other hacks would work too

Comment: It still causes flickering.

Answer (score 4):

Two possible reasons:

1. Hiding and showing is causing the scrollbar to appear and disappear, which changes the page width; or
2. The div appearing and disappearing changes the width and/or height calculations.

Other than that, we'd need a sample.

Answer (score 2):

@Stephen: Hard-coding display: none in the CSS may seem like an easy fix, but it's potentially a bad idea.  If the hidden content is important to the user, and simply being hidden on load for convenience (and is then displayed when the user, for example, clicks on a button), then display: none will permanently hide the content from those with javascript disabled.  If accessibility is a concern for you then don't use this approach...

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed this line that causes the flicker. I wrote this extension to remove the line from the show function. Note that it always sets the display element to 'block'.

I eventually solved it differently. I used a span element and changed it to a div.

```
/** fixes flicker in jQuery show function */
var fxAttrs = [
  // height animations
  [ "height", "marginTop", "marginBottom", "paddingTop", "paddingBottom" ],
  // width animations
  [ "width", "marginLeft", "marginRight", "paddingLeft", "paddingRight" ],
  // opacity animations
  [ "opacity" ]
 ];

function genFx( type, num ){
 var obj = {};
 jQuery.each( fxAttrs.concat.apply([], fxAttrs.slice(0,num)), function(){
  obj[ this ] = type;
 });
 return obj;
}

(function($){ 
    $.fn.extend({ 
 show: function(speed,callback){
  if ( speed ) {
   return this.animate(genFx("show", 3), speed, callback);
  } else {
   for ( var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++ ){
    var old = jQuery.data(this[i], "olddisplay");

    this[i].style.display = old || "";

    if ( jQuery.css(this[i], "display") === "none" ) {
     jQuery.data(this[i], "olddisplay", 'block');
    }
   }

   // Set the display of the elements in a second loop
   // to avoid the constant reflow
   for ( var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++ ){
    this[i].style.display = jQuery.data(this[i], "olddisplay") || "";
   }

   return this;
  }
 }
    }); 
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you had mentioned some divs, if you are animating more than one div at the same time can cause flickering due to multiple repaints.

1st solution, use settimeout to split each animation

2nd solution, move all the animation to css and just toggle the class and then hide it.

And use both together as follows for show and hide (using transition for opacity)

CSS

```
#you_div {
    transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

JS

```
//To show
$('#you_div').css('opacity', '0');
$('#you_div').css('display', 'block');
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#you_div').css('opacity', '1');
}, 50);

//To hide
$('#you_div').css('opacity', '0');
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#you_div').css('display', 'none');
},400);
```

Monitor repaints using devtools on your browser. The more the repaint, more flickering and lags.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed this as well.  I don't have a definite answer for you, but you might try tinkering with border/padding/margin for the element in question.

Answer (score 0):

Per John Resig in reponse to a similar complaint on the Jquery Google Group [here](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/bd8c11dc66b6d7ad/fb78b998fdf35f88?lnk=gst&q=animate+height+ie#fb78b998fdf35f88)

> Which browser? If you're in IE, then
>   this flicker is because your page is
>   in Quirks mode instead of Standards
>   mode (you'll need to provide a correct
>   DOCTYPE in order to trigger this).

Also this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111407/how-do-you-fix-the-flickering-that-occurs-when-you-use-slidetoggle-in-jquery) seems to point to the same solution.