# Rotating image causes strange flicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to rotate some images.  Works great except I get a strange "flicker" on some of the transitions.  Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?  Thank you

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" /> 
<title>Testing</title>  
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 

<style type="text/css">
#test img {position: absolute;right: 0;top: 0;}
#test img:last-child {display: none;}
</style>

<script> 
function rotateImage()
{
    var $images=$('#test img');
    $images.eq(1).attr({src : files[index]});
    $images.eq(0).fadeOut(1000);
    $images.eq(1).fadeIn(1000, function()
    {
        $images.eq(0).attr('src', files[index]);
        $images.eq(0).show();
        $images.eq(1).hide();
        if (index == files.length-1){index = 0;}else{index++;}
    });
}
var index=1,files=['f1.jpg','f2.jpg','f3.jpg'];
setInterval(rotateImage, 2000);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="test"><img src="f1.jpg" alt="" /><img src="f1.jpg" alt="f1.jpg" /></div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Everything works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/SeL3M/ . Bug is probably related with image loading. Try preloading images before using them.

Comment: Thanks kdzwinel,  Your jsfiddle example periodically shows a flicker using FF9.01/Windows.  IE8/Windows doesn't seem to have the flicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flickering is happening because of this

```
$images.eq(1).fadeIn(1000, function()
    {
        $images.eq(0).attr('src', files[index]);
        $images.eq(0).show();
        $images.eq(1).hide();
        if (index == files.length-1){index = 0;}else{index++;}
    }
);
```

After the `fadeIn` of image at index 1, source is set for image at index 0 and it is shown immediately. This results in flickering.

What you have to do is swap the images.

```
$images.eq(1).fadeIn(1000, function()
{
    $images.eq(0).remove().appendTo('#test');  // swaps the image indices
    if (index == files.length-1){index = 0;}else{index++;}
});
```

See demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/diode/SeL3M/4/

Answer (score 0):

try using the [jquery cycle](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/) plugin. in has a fade that works great

Comment: Thanks eiu165. I'd also like to figure out why it is flickering.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine in Firefox when you add a small time delay between showing and hiding an element (I've done it by using `fadeIn(100, function()` in jsfiddle bellow).

http://jsfiddle.net/SeL3M/

You can read more about this behavior here:

[unwanted "flickering" effect when using hide and show in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131760/unwanted-flickering-effect-when-using-hide-and-show-in-jquery)