# Jquery problem with a table (.animate)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want a minimize table button for my website so I was just messing around with some Jquery and i'm wondering why after the button is clicked (and it reduced its size)
it grows back to the default size? -Once the .animate has finished?

http://zombiewrath.com/maintest2.php

-Try it there,

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#tablemin { 
  height:inherit;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Click Here" onClick="dostuff();">
<div id="tablemin">
<table bordercolor="#0000FF" width="670" border="1">
        <tr>
          <td class="style5" width="400" valign="top" style="width: 300px"><b><u>Personal Feed: </u></b><br>
          </td>
          <td class="style5" width="355" valign="top"><u><strong>Live Feed:</strong> </u><br>
              <div id="ReloadTime3" style="width: 350px">  
</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="style5" valign="top" colspan="3" style="width: 488px"><b><u>Local news for Zone B-4...</u></b></td></tr>
      </table>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function dostuff() {
$("#tablemin").animate({ 
    //opacity: "0.4",
    height: "50px"
    }, 1000 );

}
//$(document.body).click(function () {
//$('#tablemin').animate({height:'1px'}, 'slow');
//$('#tablemin').fadeOut(1);
//}); 
</script>
Hi
</body></html>
```

Thanks alot,

Comment: I'm using IE 7 btw, if it doesn't expand once complete for you, please say :)

Comment: (http://zombiewrath.com/maintest.php) -if anyone wants it :P

Comment: ^Only problem is the text in the div goes weird... But I can put up with that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why after the button is clicked (and
>   it reduced its size) it grows back to
>   the default size?

with your current code, do this,

```
<style type="text/css">
#tablemin { 
  height:inherit;
  overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not grow back (in FF3.6 at least), the table just overflows it.

Comment: On Chrome 7.0 mac os neither. Your #tablemin reduces from 52px to 50px. The blue bottom border disapears during the animation, and appears when finished (because it overflows the "Hi" Text as mentioned above)

Comment: True for Safari on iPhone 3G (iOS 4.1) as well, but this answer is more of a comment, than answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code for the animation:

```
$("#tablemin").animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
    left: '+=50',
    height: 'toggle'
}, 1500);
```

You might need to add 'toggle' in height.

```
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Click Here" id="btn" onclick="dostuff();">
    <div id="tablemin">
        <table bordercolor="#0000FF" width="670" border="1">
            <tr>
                <td class="style5" width="400" valign="top" style="width: 300px">
                    <b><u>Personal Feed: </u></b>
                    <br>
                </td>
                <td class="style5" width="355" valign="top">
                    <u><strong>Live Feed:</strong> </u>
                    <br>
                    <div id="ReloadTime3" style="width: 350px">
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style5" valign="top" colspan="3" style="width: 488px">
                    <b><u>Local news for Zone B-4...</u></b>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $("#btn").click(function() {
            $("#tablemin").animate({
                opacity: 0.25,
                left: '+=50',
                height: 'toggle'

            }, 1500);
        });

    </script>
</body>
```

As for the flicker problem, you might be able to find a solution with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111407/how-do-you-fix-the-flickering-that-occurs-when-you-use-slidetoggle-in-jquery) link.

Comment: Nothing happening when I try that... (Error on page)

Answer (score 0):

Try giving #tablemin the style `overflow:hidden`