# Link flickering on mouse over

Tags: jquery, flicker

I have a image, on the image i placed a hyperlink. Now while user mouse enter into image, that hyperlink need to show, if the leave the image again the hyperlink need to hide. it is very simple i did.

the issue is, the hide/show work well. after showing the hyperlink, i need to click on that hyperlink to go next page. But the onmouseover of the hyperlink get flickering the link. it blinking. how to solve this issue?

my code which i wrote is :

```
$('img.col-image1').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).siblings('a.plus-sign').show();   
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).siblings('a.plus-sign').hide();   
    }

)
```

is any issue with my code or i need to add any special event handler to avoid the flickering onmouseover on link?

please visit here :

http://jsfiddle.net/RLfNu/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forked your solution and came up with one that worked in Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/4mhGb/

Answer (score 1):

I think your going about this the wrong way (As I've done myself).

For something as simple as this you could do it with CSS. If you wanted to animate it using jQuery.fadeIn and jQuery.fadeOut then I would use JavaScript over CSS.

See my example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5pgvC/2/

I wrapped the image and the link within another div:

```
    <div class="col-holder">
        <a class="removed plus-sign" href="publishing.html">next</a>
        <img class="col-image1" src="http://www.tnpsc.com/downloads/NaturesScenery.jpg" width="221" height="114" alt="Publishing" />

    </div>  
    <p>Whitefield has a deep heritage in the publishing industry. We know how content is developed, managed and consumed. </p>
    <a class="view-case-study" href="publishing.html"><span><strong>Read more</strong></span>
    </a>
```

Then added :hover CSS for it:

```
.col-holder:hover a.plus-sign{
    display: block;   
}
```

This will stop the flickering.

Comment: +1 for pure CSS! However I wouldn't wrap the paragraph also because the hover is triggering on the text.

Comment: Yeah true, just quickly did it. I'll amend my answer.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

as IE6 suffer from flickering event

Comment: refer [How do you fix the flickering that occurs when you use slideToggle in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111407/how-do-you-fix-the-flickering-that-occurs-when-you-use-slidetoggle-in-jquery)

Comment: No, even i get this issue in firefox

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be more semantic to wrap the items being hovered (instead of attaching hover events to separate elements).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wdm954/zS3rc/2

```
<span class="hoverimg">
    <a class="removed plus-sign" href="publishing.html">next</a>
    <img class="col-image1" src="/path" width="221" height="114" alt="Publishing" />
</span>
```

Add to CSS...

```
a.plus-sign {
    display: none;
}
```

jQuery...

```
$('.hoverimg').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('a.plus-sign').toggle();   
});
```